# Text fonts other than Cambria to match Cambria Math

Tags: fonts, typography

This may be a little bit off-topic. However I think it's still TeX related.

Recently I decided to move my personal style (a class file) to be unicode-math and fontspec based, so I can freely use some commercial fonts I have and more important, to take advantage of some opentype features.

However, as a Statistics PhD student, Math font is surely the first thing I have to decide. And after some trying I have decided to stick with Cambria math for now. Though I like euler, I don't think my supervisor will like to see it in my thesis. And the design of STIX is just too "Times Roman" and I simply don't like Times all the time. And the design of ASANA math, in my opinion still requires some improvement, especially the weights do not blend very well.

So I have to decide which text font to use with Cambria math. Though I fell Cambria math is acceptable to me, I don't like its text font.

Any suggestions are more than welcome. I have both commercial and free fonts for choice (more specific those in Adobe Font folio 11 and some others).

I would prefer a fonts with at least the following features, `smcp`, `case`, `cpsp`, `lnum`, `onum`, `tnum`, `pnum`, and of course `kern`, `liga`

In addition, I don't think the text fonts have to be similar to Cambria Math in design. This is neither a sufficient nor a necessary condition for the text and math to blend well.

Just to give a example. Arrus, designed by Lipton. If one set Arrus in body, and need some large size text for headings, then Cataneo will be a far more better choice than just scale up Arrus. If similarity is a criterion, then scaled Arrus has exactly the same shape as non-scaled Arrus. The problem is that scaling changes weight, and weights is one of the criterion for matching fonts.

I am not saying that similarity is something bad. It is just not necessary. And sometimes not sufficient. For example, Cambria and Cambria Math, they bare the same name but they do have different designs. And simply don't like Cambria's small caps.

Comment: Well, I'd still suggest you to use Cambria with Cambria Math.

Comment: If, in your opinion, design similarity is not a criterion for "matching", please explain what is.

Comment: @lockstep For example, Concrete Roman and Euler, they are not similar, but they blend very well. A match between fonts do not mean they have to look the same. Instead, their weights, slope, etc need to mix good.

Comment: @YanZhou: Concrete Roman and Euler don't blend well at all (they only match in weight, not in style, which is the most important criterion). That's not a surprise since the only reason Knuth used Concrete with Euler is because he wanted to try modifying Computer Modern to see how flexible his meta-design was (he explains so in [Typesetting Concrete Mathematics](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb10-1/tb23knut.pdf), page 32). An interesting read on font matching is Thierry Bouche's [Diversity in Math Fonts](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb19-2/tb59bouc.pdf).

Answer (score 6):

As you'll probably want a font with at least a bit of similarity to [Cambria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cambria_%28typeface%29), I suggest to give [Linux Libertine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Libertine) a try.

Comment: Linux Libertine has a great binding for LaTeX. Check out the `libertine` package! It works best with XeTeX, and also provides an organic grotesk sans serif font with the same metrics called *Biolinum*.

Answer (score 5):

Old question, but I wanted to suggest Marion by the Typodermic Foundry. Unfortunately at least the version which came with OS X doesn't have smallcaps. Here is an example (Marion/Cambria Math, 10/15*27):

[image]

(The content is from “Log canonical models for $M_{g,n}$” by Han-Bom Moon, available from arxiv)

Comment: Old answer, but I wanted to ask about Marion :P Doesn't the version which came with OS X (apart from the small caps) lack of ligatures? Apart from a little lousy spacing, may be? (I'm not an expert). By the way, great configuration ;)

Comment: @Manuel: Yes, it does lack ligatures. Also some kerning pairs are off. But I'm not sure if it's XeTeX or the font (`Va` vs. `V\kern0pt a`). By the way, Apple seems to like the font: Mountain Lion now comes with an italic and bold face of the font as well, when in Lion there was only the regular cut. Do you mean by spacing the interword spacing? Interword spacing was done by me, to m/4+.25em-.05em instead of CM's m/3 (and whatever the plus/minus components are). So the math spacings were adjusted to accommodate that change, too.

Comment: Whith spacing I meant «*some kerning pairs are off*». I have another Marion font, and I asked that because I wasn't sure if I should use the one I have (bigger size at the same points, ligatures, and —in my eye— better kerning pairs) or keep using the one which comes with OS X. **EDIT:** In fact, it has ligatures (if your directly write ﬁ or ﬁ), so the only problem is that you have to activate them.

Comment: @Manuel: Heh, `opentype-info.tex` tells me for the one which comes with OS X: “OpenType Layout features found in ‘Marion’: None”. So definitely use the other one! ;) (though, it could be because it's a .ttc -file)

Answer (score 3):

Constantia works particularly well, and its small caps & old-style figures are quite nice too.  See [this document of mine](http://cloud.github.com/downloads/jcsalomon/thesis/report-1.pdf) or this detail from it:

[image: constantia plus cambria math]

Comment: You might want to add that we assume `a(.,.,.)` is locally Lipschitz and `h(0,0)=0,g(0,0)=0` :P

Comment: :Þ indeed, @percusse. If I ever get back to working on that thesis, maybe.

Comment: Is the math font also Constantia? How do you set it up? with `\RequirePackage{unicode-math}\setmathfont{Constantine Math}`?

Comment: @AlfC, the math font is Cambria Math. I was pointing out how Constantia (a text font) worked nicely with Cambria Math, which was what the OP was asking for.

Comment: I must say that the PDF file actually looks much nicer than the above screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I came across "Caladea" a Google font made to match Cambria "metrics".  https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Google_Crosextra_Caladea_fonts .

**EDIT**: Apparently it is not a replacement for math, as in `\setmathfont{Cambria Math}`

Answer (score 0):

Some people have likened [Noticia Text](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Noticia+Text) to Cambria.

Comment: Noticia Text features only two f-ligatures (`fi` and `fl`). This may not be enough to satisfy the OP in his/her search for a ligature-rich font family

Answer (score 0):

I find Noto Serif to be a good match. [image]